# I want a shadow catcher to only catch the shadows from one specific collection of objects, how do it do that?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Title says it all, I'm rendering with cycles.

I want my object to only catch shadows projected by another collection of objects but not the rest of the scene. It would be done through script or cycles nodes (maybe with lightpath node?).